# Magento 2: Update order emails

Tags: magento2, email, transactional-mail

Where do I click to send an Order Update email? I'd like to send an email to the customer when I post out their item.

Answer (score 3):

**how to send update mail in magento**

```
 public function __construct(
  ....
 \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
 \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager, 
....
 ) {
....
$this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
$this->_objectManager= $objectManager;
....
}

 public function execute()
   {  
    $order_sales = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);//your order id 
    $orderCommentSender = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender');
    $orderCommentSender->send($order_sales, $notify='1' , $comment);// $comment yout comment
   }
```